# Parallel Calls for child level tables from parent repo itself

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping

We're using JPA + Hibernate with our Hana database. Below is the db model as such..

VehicleModel {

1. salesModel
2. financialModel
3. maintenanceModel

}
*

Now the repository is at Master entity Vehicle and when I'm try to access the vehicle with id vehicleRepository.findById(id), all the associated child tables query are being sent in sequence. Is there any way to fire it in parallel.

Please check dynatrace calls as below

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/39522

I tried multiple conifguration but didn't work

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.